# Correction in "He is very honest to deceive anyone"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I wrote

> He is very honest to decieve none
> and

> He is very honest not to deceive anyone.

These 2 sentences are framed by me as alternatives so there might be an error. Kindly explain where and why?

Does it means the same as

> He is so honest that he can't deceive anyone

Comment: #He is very honest to decieve none
#He is very honest not to decieve anyone.
These 2 sentences are framed by me as alternatives so there might be an error. Kindly explain where and why??

Comment: It's "deceive" not "decieve". I before E except after C. With a very few exceptions.

Comment: @Prime IIRC there are more exceptions than words that actually follow the rule...

Comment: Neither of your two sentences seem correct to me although the last one is fine.

Comment: @randomhead Perhaps I should have finished the mnemonic: "... except pronouncing as "a", as in 'neighbour' and 'weigh' ". Now: your exceptions please? (said Sheila, seizing Keith) Oh, and I'll grant you "concierge".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Very honest" is wrong in that use.
This is correct:

> He is too honest to deceive anyone.

Both "so honest" and "too honest" imply a threshold of comparison.
"Very honest" does not imply a threshold.

Comment: Well i know that "too " and "so" structure but is there any way to make it correct by retaining very

Comment: @Florida: Not really, in *current* English. A century or two ago (or maybe in some "literary" contexts) you might have said something like *He is **so very honest** that he would never deceive anyone*, but I doubt *anyone* would include the intensifier ***very*** there today, even if they were prepared to use the rest of that relatively long-winded way of saying what Jack has so succinctly rephrased above. If you wanted to include an intensifier there, you could go with *He is **far** too honest to deceive anyone.*

Comment: Ok so i should use very only in positive sentences

Comment: 3 people (not incl me) voted to close the question as "proofreading". But obviously Jack and myself think the issue here is that you need guidance on how ***so*** and ***too*** differ from ***very*** in this context. And "threshold of comparison" looks good to me for that.